# how to solve SurfaceAttrib not implemented while creating pop_up window in android?

Tags: android, popupwindow

i have developed one app with action bar with overflow button.if i click first item in that one pop up window.but it shows some error like W/EGL_emulation(1587): egl SurfaceAttrib not implemented.